# what the correct userAgent about IE11

Tags: user-agent, internet-explorer-11

when I get the userAgent of my IE 11 use navigator.userAgent,I get this string:
**

> "Mozilla/5.0 (MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2;
>   .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media
>   Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; rv:11.0) like Gecko"

**
so when i get the version of my IE by jquery 1.9,it return msie9,buy the real version is ie11。but in my other pc ,I install the ie11 too,it return the userAgent is :

> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; rv:11.0) like Gecko"

but why they are different,in the top one ,the userAgent contain the word "MSIE 9.0"?

Answer (score 1):

The second option is what IE 11 should report as the browser version:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Also, JQuery 1.9 isn't the latest JQuery version, so the browser detection logic might not be up to date.

Comment: thanks ,but why the IE11 in my diferent Pc return the diferent userAgent。and the one contain the string "MSIE 9.0".I am sure I did not change the browser's userAgent.